# Recursion error when trying to minimize

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

```
FindMinimumPlot[x^2, {{x, 0.1}}, 
  Method -> Newton, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 16}]
```

The above is my code, I'm trying to minimize `x^2` using Newton's method.  I'm getting

> $RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {x->1.57033,y->0.82198}.

For the life of me I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post the full code, including the package used. I tried your code with `Optimization` `UnconstrainedProblems` package, and it seems to work.

Comment: that is the full code, how do I get that package. Apologies Im very new to mathematica

Comment: @PabloEscobar the fact that you get an error means you already loaded something which contains `FindMinimumPlot`. Wasn't it ``<< Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems` ``? Try to quit the kernel, load the package and evaluate your code again, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"  *)

<< Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`

FindMinimumPlot[x^2, {{x, 0.1}},
 Method -> Newton,
 PlotStyle -> {Thick},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 16},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: same error when I run that

Comment: @PabloEscobar - What Mma version are you using?

Comment: 11.1           26 characters

Comment: @PabloEscobar - start with a fresh kernel.